# How can I remove the browser 404 error when I use weather icon in openweathermap API?

Tags: react-native, http-status-code-404, openweathermap

[browser error 404 and well-rendered clouds icon image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2FkT.png)

I am making weather app in react native. **I encountered this 404 error continuously even though I get weather image(clouds icon) correctly from the openweathermap image link.**

The code where I get weather icon from openweathermap API is here.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { axiosClient } from 'api/axiosClient';
import { UNITS } from 'api/const';
import { useGeolocation } from './useGeolocation';
import { WeatherType } from 'types/weatherType';

const defaultWeatherData = {
  ... // omit
  weatherIcon: '',
};

export const useWeather = () => {
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] =
    useState<WeatherType>(defaultWeatherData);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const { lat, lon } = await useGeolocation();

      try {
        const { data: weatherData } = await axiosClient.get(
          `/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=${UNITS}&appid=${process.env.API_KEY}`
        );

        setWeatherData({
          ... // omit
          weatherIcon: weatherData.weather[0].icon || '01d', // '01d' is equal to 'Sunny' Icon. I put this as a default of weatherIcon property.
        });
      } catch (err: any) {
        setError(err);
        console.log(err);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    if (isLoading) {
      fetchData();
    }
  }, []);

  return [weatherData, isLoading, error] as [WeatherType, boolean, any];
};
```

And here is App.tsx.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Date, Icon, Const } from './utils';
import { COLOR } from './styles/color';
import { useWeather } from 'hooks/useWeather';

export default function App() {
  const [weatherData, isLoading, error] = useWeather();

  const {
    weatherIcon,
    ... // omit
  } = weatherData;

  const weatherIconUrl = `https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${weatherIcon}.png`;

  return (
    ...
    <View style={styles.main}>
      <Text style={styles.temp}>{temp}°</Text>
      <Text style={styles.weather}>{weather}</Text>
      <Image
        source={{ uri: weatherIconUrl }} // Here!
        style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
      />
    </View>
    ...
  );
```

**The weatherIcon is well rendered in browser view. But I repeatedly get 404 error in the browser console.**

Existing browser and editor and accessing again was not working.

I was expecting the 404 error would be gone when the icon was well rendered.